# Failed to execute command: node @nestjs/schematics:guard --name=book --no-dry-run --no-skipImport --language="ts" --sourceRoot="src" --spec

Tags: nodejs, nestjs

Error al crear Controller-Controlador Schematics en Nestjs-nodeJs

Me genera el siguiente error al crear un nuevo controlador en Nestjs

```
Failed to execute command: node @nestjs/schematics:guard --name=book --no-dry-run --no-skipImport --language="ts" --sourceRoot="src" --spec
```

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada,de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Answer (score 0):

Lo logre solucionar agregando `--flat`al final

Ejemplo para crear controlador:
`nest g co NAMECONTROLLER --flat`

Mas info en la documentacion oficial
[CLI command reference](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/usages)

Answer (score 0):

Tambien podria ser porque no hay modulo cerca que esté difinido,

```
-node_modules
-src
     ->Micarpeta
          --.controller.ts
          --.**module.ts**

     ->OtraCarpeta
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).